# How can I normalize the data in a range of columns in my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas data frame surveyData:

I want to normalize the data in each column by performing:

```
surveyData_norm = (surveyData - surveyData.mean()) / (surveyData.max() - surveyData.min())
```

This would work fine if my data table only contained the columns I wanted to normalize. However, I have some columns containing string data preceding like:

```
Name  State  Gender  Age  Income  Height
Sam   CA     M        13   10000    70
Bob   AZ     M        21   25000    55
Tom   FL     M        30   100000   45
```

I only want to normalize the Age, Income, and Height columns but my above method does not work becuase of the string data in the name state and gender columns.

Comment: cant you use try: ....   except ValueError: ...... pattern. You can pass the normalization function on string columns. There might be more more 'pandastic' way of doing though.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can perform operations on a sub set of rows or columns in pandas in a number of ways.  One useful way is indexing:

```
# Assuming same lines from your example
cols_to_norm = ['Age','Height']
survey_data[cols_to_norm] = survey_data[cols_to_norm].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```

This will apply it to only the columns you desire and assign the result back to those columns.  Alternatively you could set them to new, normalized columns and keep the originals if you want.

Comment: People who read this answer be careful, the formula for normalization is wrong. The `mean` should be changed to `min` in the `lambda` function.

Comment: Yep. If what you are after is feature scaling each column [0,1] then, as @Amin says, use (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()) as the formula

Comment: is there really no built in function that just does this automatically?

Answer (score 11):

I think it's better to use 'sklearn.preprocessing' in this case which can give us much more scaling options.
The way of doing that in your case when using StandardScaler would be:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
cols_to_norm = ['Age','Height']
surveyData[cols_to_norm] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(surveyData[cols_to_norm])
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple way and way more efficient:
Pre-calculate the mean:
`dropna()` avoid missing data.

```
mean_age = survey_data.Age.dropna().mean()
max_age = survey_data.Age.dropna().max()
min_age = survey_data.Age.dropna().min()

dataframe['Age'] = dataframe['Age'].apply(lambda x: (x - mean_age ) / (max_age -min_age ))
```

this way will work...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's really nice to use built-in functions

```
# Assuming same lines from your example
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
cols_to_norm = ['Age','Height']
survey_data[cols_to_norm] = scaler.fit_transform(survey_data[cols_to_norm])
```

Answer (score 0):

MinMax normalize all numeric columns with `minmax_scale`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
# cols = ['Age', 'Height']
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = minmax_scale(df[cols])
```

*Note: Keeps index, column names or non-numerical variables unchanged.*

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# let Dataset here be your data#

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
minmax = MinMaxScaler()

for x in dataset.columns[dataset.dtypes == 'int64']:
    Dataset[x] = minmax.fit_transform(np.array(Dataset[I]).reshape(-1,1))
```