# How to normalize just one column of a dataframe while keeping the others unaffected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Assuming we have a `df` as follows:

```
id A  B
50 1  5
60 2  6
70 3  7
80 4  8
```

I would like to know as to how can normalize just the `column B`, between 0 and 1, while keeping the other columns `id` and `column A` completely unaffected?

**Edit 1:** If I do the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : ['50', '60', '70', '80'],
        'A' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'B' : ['5', '6', '7', '8']
        })

from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.values[:,[2]])
```

I get the `X_minmax` as follows

```
0
0.333333
0.666667
1
```

I want these 4 values to be placed in place of the column `B` in the dataframe `df` without changing the other 2 columns looking as below:

```
    id A  B
    50 1  0
    60 2  0.333333
    70 3  0.666667
    80 4  1
```

Comment: do you mean `df.B=df.B/df.B.max()` ? if not can you post the expected?

Comment: Hey @anky_91, I have edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I normalize the data in a range of columns in my pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576540/how-can-i-normalize-the-data-in-a-range-of-columns-in-my-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this.

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as preprocessing
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[50,60,70,80],'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[5,6,7,8]})
float_array = df['B'].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_array = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(float_array)
df['B']=scaled_array
```

Comment: Perfect. Was looking for something like this :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can reassign the value of the column:

```
df.B = (df.B - df.B.mean()) / (df.B.max() - df.B.min())
```

Comment: Hey, @dzang. Thank you for the response. The values when I do this method range from -1 to 1. What can I do if I need the values between 0 and 1?

Comment: `df.B = (df.B - df.B.min()) / (df.B.max() - df.B.min())`

Comment: See Quang comment